# IIS7 - Bind virtual directory to different IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server

I have a website hosted with IIS7 (www.mysite.com).

I want to configure virtual directories to point to different IP addresses, with a logical name off of my site.

For example, I want www.mysite.com/server1 to point to a specific IP address, but still show the URL like it is directly integrated with my site.

Is this possible?  So far, the only thing I've seen close is HTTP Redirect for the Virtual Directory, which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this is possible.

It should possible to configure the site to use the IP Address you want and have the main site redirect in some way.

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this kind of thing though.

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't seem possible. As far as I've seen, IP addresses can be bound to sites, but not virtual directories.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you put the virtual directory on second IIS with a different IP, then use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to redirect user from the first IIS to the second IIS. IIS URL Rewrite uses Application Request Routing(APR) and APR can point the user to the different server and still show the URL as a part of your site. You can find more detilas of APR on [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/486/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing/)